# Redis PubSub Reconnect with Jedis

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, jedis, azure-redis-cache

Trying to include the code related to azure redis autoreconnect if any network error occurred in Redis PubSub connection. Any help/advice would be appreciable. Below is my Redis Config code.

```
 public class RedisConfig 
   {    
    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory jedis = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        jedis.setHostName("redishostname");
        jedis.setPassword("redispassword");
        jedis.setPort(redisport);
        return jedis;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
        return template;
    }   

    @Bean
    RedisMessageListenerContainer redisContainer() {
        final RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        container.setTaskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4));     
        return container;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following client library specific guidance ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-best-practices#client-library-specific-guidance)) for Azure Cache for Redis and the information available for [Jedis (Java)](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/925630df72be1351b21440625ff2671f#file-redis-bestpractices-java-jedis-md).

There is a [PoolUsage.java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-redis-cache-samples/blob/master/Java/ClientSamples/src/main/java/jedis/PoolUsage.java) example and a [ClusterUsage.java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-redis-cache-samples/blob/master/Java/ClientSamples/src/main/java/jedis/ClusterUsage.java) example.

As for a specific example for PubSub Reconnect, please see the following Stack Overflow post: [jedis pubsub and timeouts: how to listen infinitely as subscriber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609491/jedis-pubsub-and-timeouts-how-to-listen-infinitely-as-subscriber)

```
private AkkaStarter2(){
//0 specifying no timeout.. Overlooked this 100 times
sub = new Jedis(REDISHOST, REDISPORT,0);
akkaListener = new AkkaListener();
}
```